# "Error: Unexpected, Please Try Again" with GoogleBigQuery JOIN

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I know this is an older issue with Google BigQuery, but it seems the problem had been fixed @ mid 2013.  I wanted to know if there has been any recent workarounds/fixes to this issue in the recent months. Here is my query from the google sample data.

```
SELECT publicdata:samples.natality.mother_age, publicdata:samples.gsod.station_number
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
INNER JOIN [publicdata:samples.gsod]
ON publicdata:samples.gsod.year = publicdata:samples.natality.year
LIMIT 100
```

---

```
Query Failed
Error: Unexpected. Please try again.
```

Job ID: deft-grammar-553:job_eUkW4EhgNvlJPuWPoP1bLL7Ra_w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the report! That error message should be improved.

In the meantime: The same query using table aliases works well (though I had to change the JOIN to JOIN EACH to deal with the size of both tables).

Instead of:

```
SELECT publicdata:samples.natality.mother_age, publicdata:samples.gsod.station_number
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality]
INNER JOIN [publicdata:samples.gsod]
ON publicdata:samples.gsod.year = publicdata:samples.natality.year
LIMIT 100
```

Do:

```
SELECT a.mother_age, b.station_number
FROM [publicdata:samples.natality] a 
INNER JOIN EACH [publicdata:samples.gsod] b
ON a.year = b.year
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Do you mind filling me in on whether this is an error with bigQuery, itself, or something I am not understanding / doing right?

Comment: I'd say you are doing it right, while BigQuery is being restrictive on requesting table aliases instead of full names as you had. The long term goal is removing these restrictions, while the shorter term one is having better error messages than "Error: Unexpected"

Comment: ok, thanks for the response.  We are trying to figure out whether bigQuery is the right choice for our emerging BI application,  but I was slightly worried that it didn't support joins.